# Using $u(t,\gamma(t,x))=\gamma_t(t,x)$ to find various partial derivatives of $\gamma$ in terms of $u$

Tags: systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

I have two functions $u:\mathbb{R}\times S^1\rightarrow S^1$ and $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\times S^1\rightarrow S^1$ related via this composition $u(t,\gamma(t,x))=\gamma_t(t,x)$ (call this equation $(1)$), where the subscript denotes the partial derivative with respect to $t$. I need to compute the partials $\gamma_x,\gamma_{tx},\gamma_{xx},\gamma_{ttx},\gamma_{txx}$ and express them in terms of $u$, using only $(1)$. So, I differentiate with respect to $x$ to find
$$u_x(t,\gamma(t,x))\gamma_x(t,x)=\gamma_{tx}(t,x).$$
Then I differentiate this result with respect to $x$ and $t$, respectively, to find
$$u_{xx}(t,\gamma(t,x))\gamma^2_x(t,x)+u_x(t,\gamma(t,x))\gamma_{xx}(t,x)=\gamma_{txx}(t,x)$$
$$u_x(t,\gamma(t,x))\gamma_{xt}(t,x)+\gamma_x(t,x)\big(u_{xt}(t,\gamma(t,x))+u_{xx}(t,\gamma(t,x))\gamma_t(t,x)\big)=\gamma_{ttx}(t,x).$$
I can then use $(1)$ to get rid of $\gamma_t(t,x)$ in the last equation. This leaves me with $3$ equations, and 5 unknowns (the partials $\gamma_x,\gamma_{tx},\gamma_{xx},\gamma_{ttx},\gamma_{txx}$). If I differentiate $(1)$ with respect to $t$, then although I get another equation, I also introduce the derivative $\gamma_{tt},$ which I don't need. Similarly, if I take higher order derivatives, then I'm introducing unknowns that I don't need. I simply don't see how this can be done. I know this isn't the most exciting problem to think about, but if someone sees a mistake I made or something I'm missing that would allow me to solve for $\gamma_x,\gamma_{tx},\gamma_{xx},\gamma_{ttx},\gamma_{txx}$ in terms of $u$, I would very much appreciate it.